# Affect to elements of owner window

Tags: c#, winforms

This app consists from 2 windows; there is the Label in owner window, `indicator1` name assigned. The method `IndicatorOn()` must to change the label's appearance, however it happen only if to call `IndicatorOn()` from the same window (`Main Window`) and zero effect if to call it from the other window like in my app. I tried to debug - everything seems all right: the program successfully enter to `case 1` block and exit it, just the commands related with `indicator1` has been ignored...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ChildWindow childWindow = new ChildWindow();
        childWindow.Owner = this;
        childWindow.Show();
    }

    public void IndicatorOn (byte indicatorNumber) { // assume that it cout is small
        switch (boothNumber) {
            case 1:
                indicator1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                indicator1.BackgroundImage = ExamopleProject.Properties.Resources.IndicatorActive;
                indicator1.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
                break;
            }
            // ....
    }
}

public partial class ChildWindow : Form {

    MainWindow mainWindow;

    public ChildWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: In `ChildWindow` you have `mainWindow = new MainWindow();` and in `MainWindow` you have `ChildWindow childWindow = new ChildWindow();`...what are you trying to do?

Comment: This is a common problem with many answers here. You are initializing a NEW instance of MainWindow. This instance is an object by itself, it is not a reference to the current existing MainWindow. Of course whatever you do with this instance is confined to this NEW instance and it doesn't affect the instance already on screen. If you call Show on this NEW instance you will see your changes.

Comment: I see, `MainWindow mainWindow; public ChildWindow(MainWindow mainWindowReference) { InitializeComponent(); mainWindow = mainWindowReference; }` is works. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Or... since `ChildWindow` is always owned by `MainWindow`, you could just use the `ChildWindow`'s `Owner` property to get a reference to your original `MainWindow`...

Comment: Yes that's a common way to solve the problem. However it creates a strict binding within MainWindow and ChildWindow. This could be a non-issue in your context but usually I prefer to solve this relationship using events raised by the child window and handled in the main window. In this way your ChildWindow is reusable also where a MainWindow doesn't exist. As I have said this could be a no-issue here.